# Possible to set dynamic terminal title via escape sequence in vscode now that terminal.integrated.titleMode is deprecated?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Apparently VSCODE removed the ability to set a custom terminal title via escape sequence last year, is it possible to still do this via another means?

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133112

This was possible by setting **terminal.integrated.titleMode** to **sequence** previously.

Here is the setting as described before being removed:

```
[TerminalSettingId.TitleMode]: {
    description: localize('terminal.integrated.titleMode', "Determines how the terminal's title is set, this shows up in the terminal's tab or dropdown entry."),
    type: 'string',
    enum: ['executable', 'sequence'],
    markdownEnumDescriptions: [
        localize('titleMode.executable', "The title is set by the terminal, the name of the detected foreground process will be used."),
        localize('titleMode.sequence', "The title is set by the process via an escape sequence, this is useful if your shell dynamically sets the title.")
    ],
    default: 'executable'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting was replaced by the more flexible `terminal.integrated.tabs.title` and `terminal.integrated.tabs.description`. For the equivalent of the old `'sequence'` use:

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.title": "${sequence}"
```

But it's much more flexible than that now, for example:

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.title": "${process}${separator}${sequence}"
"terminal.integrated.tabs.description": "${workspaceFolder}"
```